# How to subtract the contents of the cells using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want subtract my table cells content. I want subtract zus from result. 
How to do this?

```
<tr id="rowPen">
    <td>Price</td>
    <td id="result" class="dozus">0</td>
</tr>

<tr id="rowZUS">
    <td>ZUS</td>
    <td id="zus">0</td>
</tr>
```

I tried take it to variables

```
var wyp = document.getElementById("result");

var w = document.getElementById("zus");
```

but i don't know what next :/

result i want show in cell id="pays"

Comment: you could do `wyp.innerHTML = "hello";` or `wyp.id = "pays";` -- because you are using numeric values in `zus` and `dozus` if you grab the contents with `.innerHTML` you will be given a string which then if you do `w.innerHTML += 4` you might not get the expected result. Instead use `parseInt( w.innerHTML )`. Maybe this answers a few questions?

Comment: What is stopping you from googling "javascript subtract variables"? Take the variables, do the math, and set the result. This is very basic, very google-able stuff.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I guess OP doesn't know how to read number from cell content. Math probably is not a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read textContent of the table cells and subtract them:

```js
var wyp = document.getElementById("result");
var w = document.getElementById("zus");

document.getElementById("pays").textContent = wyp.textContent - w.textContent;
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="rowPen">
    <td>Price</td>
    <td id="result" class="dozus">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="rowZUS">
    <td>ZUS</td>
    <td id="zus">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="pays"></div>
```